# SQL Determining the length of a unique visit from access log

Tags: sql, sqlite, jdbc, access-log

I have a table that has access log records and I want to know the average time of a visit. I'm using sqlite with JDBC to populate the table. The table could be potentially a few 100 million rows large. I don't have much SQL experience.

The table is similar to this:

```
ID   Name      Time(s)
1    Apricot   100
2    Apricot   101
3    Banana    102
4    Banana    102
5    Banana    105
6    Apricot   106
7    Apricot   300
8    Cake      300
9    Banana    310
10   Banana    320
```

I want to see the duration of each visit. One visit is when an entry appears and continues to appear (with the same name) until some time has passed (say 100 seconds). After that, the session ends - if the same name appears again then it is a new session.

Ultimately I want to graph the number of visits and their durations.

I'm not sure what kind of output would be the easiest, but here is a possible output that would be useful:

```
Name       Time
Banana     3     (row5 - row3)
Apricot    6     (row6 - row1)
Apricot    0     (row7 - last visit is >100s and no more subsequent visits)
Cake       0     (row8 - last visit is >100s and no more subsequent visits)
Banana     10    (row10 - row9)
```

(Additionally, show the ID - this could be the ID of the start of a visit or the end)

**How can this be done using SQL?**

This page: [Determining the length of a user's visit based on SQL timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380338/determining-the-length-of-a-users-visit-based-on-sql-timestamps) 
has a similar question to mine but I don't really understand the answer, nor does it work for me (my DB browser freezes).